# how to filter more than one level JQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

i've three method Json that filtering in Four levels
First : Governrate
second : Area
third : Location
four : ATMId

and method Json for each one like this

```
  public ActionResult FilteringArea(int Id)
    {
        var selectArea = db.Areas.Where(r => r.GovernateId == Id)
            .Select(r => new { label = r.Name, id = r.Id });

        return Json(selectArea, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and i use to filter in my view this function

```
$('#AreaId').on('change', function () {
        getATM($(this).find('option:selected'));            
        getLocation($(this).find('option:selected'));           
    });

    var getATM = function (obj) {
        var $input = $(obj);
        var jsonData = {
            "AreaId": $input.val()
        };
        var addressData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/reports/FilteringATM',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: addressData,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ATMId").find('option').remove().end();
                $("#ATMId").parent("div").find(".e-select-options").find("ul").find("li").remove().end();
                $("#ATMId").parent("div").find(".e-select-selected").text("-- ِAll--");
                $("#ATMId").append("<option value=''>-- All--</option>").end();
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        //$("#ATMId").parent("div").find(".e-select-selected").text(result[i].label);
                        //$("#ATMId").append("<option value=" + result[i].id + " selected='selected'>" + result[i].label + "</option>").end();
                    }
                    $("#ATMId").append("<option value=" + result[i].id + ">" + result[i].label + "</option>").end();
                    $("#ATMId").parent("div").find(".e-select-options").find("ul").append("<li class='undefined'>" + result[i].label + "</li>");
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

and  getLocation($(this).find('option:selected')); exactly like previous function
the problem is when try to change the first level (area again) the third level and so fourth still not changed so any Idea about solve this problem ?

Comment: try it : result without [i]

Comment: but how without i filling result ? the problem that occur is when loading new items again

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/